# The "RemoveField" function is removing the last element instead of the passed index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Here is the reducer, the RemoveField function is removing the last element from the number of fields array instead of the passed index

```
const UiReducer = createSlice({
      name: 'ui',
      initialState: {
        name: 'User',
        numberOfFields: [0],
        numberOfSubFields: [0],
      },
      reducers: {
        setName(state, action) {
          state.name = action.payload;
        },
        AddField(state, action) {
          state.numberOfFields = [...state.numberOfFields, action.payload];
        },
        RemoveField(state, action) {
          console.log(action.payload);
          state.numberOfFields.splice(action.payload, 1);
        },
      },
    });
```

Comment: I think that you must be dispatching the wrong index when you call `dispatch(RemoveField(n))`.  I tried your code and it works just fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-array-of-numbers-2jeum?file=/src/components/App.tsx

Comment: Hi @LindaPaiste and thanks for taking the time out to help me. The problem was that react wasn't picking up on the key, I explicitly added an id field and then it could differentiate between the keys

Comment: Do not add "Resolved" to your question's title. Either post an answer below detailing how you solved the issue, or delete the question if you feel this won't benefit anyone else.

Comment: @TimLewis okay got it